# How to find the second latest file in folder

Tags: c#, linq, file

I want to access a folder through my C# code,and open up the **2nd** most recently updated/created file. This is because the most recent file is always being used by a different process, so I cannot access it properly.

I have found code to find the most recent file, and it is:

```
var DataLogFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
                   orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                   select f).First();
```

I am unsure of how to edit it in order to find the file I am looking for. I know it'll probably be the one after the first one in descending order, but I have no idea how to access it.

Comment: If you need more options - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+linq+take+second+item. Note that in general (non-IO-bound) case you may be better of not sorting but *selecting* item (O(n log n) for sorting vs. O(n) for selecting).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are in the right way, you just need to [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) one time to get the specified file :

```
 var DataLogFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
                           orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                           select f).Skip(1).First();
```

This assumes you have at least two files in `directory`.

Comment: And if there is only one file in the directory? (hint: throws an exception)

Comment: How can it's the way to get the last 3 files updated?